# Wordpress front-page.php template

Tags: php, wordpress

I have my front page set to a static page and am trying to build my custom template. How do I actually show the selected front page in front-page.php? I have googled and googled but can't seem to figure out how to do it.

The front-page.php actually loads like it should, but I can't seem to find documentation on exactly how to show the page that is assigned as the static home page. Any suggestions?

I have tried

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); ?>
    <?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>
<?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
```

but that didn't seem to work...

Comment: If you set a page to be the home page in Settings -> Reading then wordpress will automatically apply the template front-page.php without it having to be selected in the template menu. The standard Loop will then use that particular post without any custom queries.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I was looping and calling the template content-page.php which actually has the info of the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing something obvious. The loop I was using I had copied out of wordpress template. It actually called another template file. What I should have used was:

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
                <header class="entry-header">
                    <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                </header>

                <div class="entry-content">
                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                    <?php wp_link_pages(array('before' => '<div class="page-links">' . __('Pages:', 'twentytwelve'), 'after' => '</div>')); ?>
                </div><!-- .entry-content -->
                <footer class="entry-meta">
                    <?php edit_post_link(__('Edit', 'twentytwelve'), '<span class="edit-link">', '</span>'); ?>
                </footer><!-- .entry-meta -->
            </article><!-- #post -->
<?php   endwhile;?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your static page uses a page template (usually page.php for the default template)

You can create a new one for the homepage if you wish. see :  [Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates) copy `page.php` to `homepage.php` and change the template name

Example template (homepage.php) :

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Homepage
*/

//the content of page.php and now you can do what you want.
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$id = 0; /* The id of your page */
$page = get_page($id);
echo apply_filters('the_content', $page->post_content);
```

If its a static page, I should not use a loop.

Answer (score 0):

First, take a look to [topic to show something only on home page](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/show-something-only-on-home-page-1). a related question is [Wordpress Post Thumbnail Issue (Only 1 thumbnail on frontpage)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12557268/wordpress-post-thumbnail-issue-only-1-thumbnail-on-frontpage). Also, it can be useful [how to create a static front page in wordpress](http://themes.required.ch/news/how-to-create-a-static-front-page-in-wordpress/).